# Python: ImportError: cannot import name X

Tags: python, import, module, package, importerror

I have cloned a github Repo [PyCMake](https://github.com/PyCMake/PyCMake), and got into the root folder of the project. **ImpPackage**(Package containing several module) and **maker.py**(have some imports from ImpPackage) are the two files in this folder.

- ***PyCMake***/
  +Readme & many more things
  +setup.py
  +**pycmake**/

  - __init__
  - **maker**.py
  - **ImpPackages**/
    +__init__
    +contains many .py modules

maker.py

> ```
>     ....    
>     from pycmake import ImpPackage    
>     ...    
>     ...
> ```

*When I run*

```
$python maker.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycmake/maker.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pycmake import ImpPackage
ImportError: cannot import name ImpPackage
```

**But when I make maker.py as**:

> ```
>     ....    
>     import ImpPackage    #removed 'from'
>     ...    
>     ...
> ```

Its working fine.
I want the import statement to be

> ```
>     from pycmake import ImpPackage
> ```

because its a Open Source Project. How will I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `abc` in this code?

Comment: Don't name your module the same thing as a built-in Python module, it'll only end in tears.

Comment: Yea..sorry I didn't know it was a built-in Module. Actually the module name is 'pycmake'. I will edit the question now.

Comment: Is the problem solved? "it" as in "abc" is a inbuilt module?? lol, yea it will indeed end it tears, I had one similar problem with the word set, i guess.

Comment: Nopw the problem isn't solved.

Comment: Mention about the folder hierarchy and the repo you cloned too. We could try it and narrow your problem down.

Comment: @nabeel Can you do an import pycmake on your terminal? And from pycmake import ImpPackage?

Comment: [PyCMake](https://github.com/PyCMake/PyCMake "PyCMake")

Comment: yea I can import it from the terminal.